# ASP:Checkbox server tag not well formed

Tags: asp.net, checkbox

I have this line of code:

```
 <asp:CheckBox runat="server" id="chkSelected"  Checked='<%# Not IsDBNull(Eval("EntityID"))%>' onchange="AssignValues('<%# Eval("EntityID")%>', '<%# Eval("id") %>', document.getElementById(this)  );" />
```

It doesn't like what I've got going on for the parameters for `AssignValues(...)` but it's just fine with `Checked='<%# Not IsDBNull(Eval("EntityID"))%>'`

What am I doing wrong here?

Edit: the last parameter should be the .ClientID of the control... I know `document.getElementById()` won't work there.

Comment: You can just use `this` instead of `document.getElementById(this)`

Comment: Yeah, that's not what it's complaining about though :(

Comment: it seems some of your records have no entityid --> it's null. can u change to IF(IsDBNull( Eval("EntityID")), -1, Eval("EntityID"))

Comment: That part works just fine... Like I said, it doesn't like the parameters for the `AssignValues` signature.. .oh, I see what you're saying

Comment: It doesn't like that either

Comment: If you can (not sure with checkbox/onchange), consider putting things that are more complex than a simple databind/eval into the codebehind. You will find it easier to debug and deal with later.

Comment: It was inside of a datagrid. I have an outstanding request from my boss to put all the columns on the front side so that he can see it at a glance in code view without having to dig through server side code. If you look at haraman's answer, he may have the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last parameter should be like this

```
onchange='<%# String.Format("AssignValues(\"{0}\", \"{1}\", \"{2}\");", Eval("EntityID"), Eval("id"), this) %>'
```

In your case the issue was related to multiple evals and multiple quotes. However multiple Eval calls can be made using single # sign

Comment: I'll try this next time I have to do something similar. For now, I ended up using custom attributes - the project requirements changed so that I didn't need the clientside javascript call. That made it a lot simpler.